# How can I write a regular expression to recognize the plus operator and the plus sign?

Tags: c#, regex, lexical-analysis

I am trying to write a lexical analyzer for C# language, but I can't  figure out how can I differentiate the plus sign from the plus operator, except the context.
 I need the next token from the source file. So, when I encounter a + how do I now it refers to a declaration of some integer, real, whatever or it refers to + operator?
How can my scannig function differentiate these two situations appropriately?
The case is similar to this < and <=, <<, but in my situation next character does't help every time.

```
int a = +1;
a=2 + 3;
```

Comment: this `(?<=\d)\+(?=\d)` would match the operator plus.

Comment: What will you do about `a+=2`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 That is a totally separate case for a totally different operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to write a lexical analyzer for C# language

OK, but you misplaced the your lexer/parser separation bar here.

The lexer's job is to *"cut"* the input string into tokens. The parser's job is to interpret these. Your lexer should just detect the `+` operator, emit the corresponding token, and that's it.

Then, your parser, **which has context knowledge** (ie it knows which part of an expression it is trying to parse at a given moment) is in a much better position to make the difference between an unary and a binary operator. The lexer simply lacks the necessary information.

Obviously, you shouldn't include the `-` sign either into number tokens.

Here are some lexing examples:

`int a=+1;` --> `int` `a` `=` `+` `1` `;`

`a=2+3;` --> `a` `=` `2` `+` `3` `;`

Note the `+` `1` in the first case. Your lexer shouldn't emit `+1`.

Comment: Thank you! Now I figure out how to solve this. Have a nice day.

Comment: But now I face a new problem. This situation is the same as this;

Comment: But I face a new problem. How do I deal with this situation: < and <=. I read that lexical analyzer is supposed to recognize them and not the parser. It is fair to treat plus specialy?

Comment: @user2991856 The lexer should emit `<=` as a single token in this case. If you encounter `<` immediately followed by `=` then emit `<=`, if it's followed by something else, then emit a `<`. Templates will be the tough part for the `>` though (recognize the `>>` operator vs `>` `>` in `Func<List<T>>` for instance)